# Any way to find the Ajax Request from which page or function in PHP MVC?

Tags: php, ajax, bitrix

I am working on Bitrix24 CRM which is based on PHP. I want find the the ajax request url called page(source) or function.
Is there ant way to find Ajax request source page or function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Chrome's Developer Tools, go to the Sources tab, and open the XHR/Fetch Breakpoints section in the right sidebar. Check the box labeled "Any XHR or fetch". Then when an AJAX request is sent, the debugger will pause the application and show you the source line where the request is coming from.